# Create Unlimited Sprite Nodes Sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

If anyone knows how to do this, I have a sprite node that I want to position all around the screen "Like stars" and I want to create a field node that pulls the "stars" to the center of the screen as more stars spawn basically creating a vortex like action.

This is how I created the node in this "addObjects" function, How is it that I can have this "stars" effect? and have them come towards the center of the screen unlimitedly? thanks a bunch

```
func addObjects() {
    for (var i=0 ; i<5 ; i++) {
        let PositiveNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy1")
        PositiveNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: PositiveNode.frame.size.width/2)
        PositiveNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.addChild(PositiveNode)
       }
```

I had a thought that maybe making a for loop could help me achieve my goal , but I'm probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate a black hole effect you can use a `radialGravityField` SKFieldNode. As for an unlimited number of stars, you can create SKSpriteNodes and remove them from the scene once they reach a predefined position. That being the center of radial gravity field.

The important thing here is to `removeFromParent` as to avoid a memory leak caused by constantly creating new nodes without removing the ones in the center.

Comment: But how else will you know the black hole is full if you dont get an outOfMemoryException ;-) I would suggest a type of bounding box in which they are deleted though than just a singular spot.

Comment: I understand that I should create an SKFieldNode in order to obtain my desired results. However what I'm having trouble with is having the field node affect the stars . More precisely Im having trouble setting up the fieldbitmasks, thats what I think I'm lacking in, in making this effect work